# Drawing rectangle around detected object?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I dont know why it does not detect my template window .I mean I have scattered bounding box all over the image just like detect.jpg that I have sent .Do you know what is wrong with this algorithm?(detectobj is algorithms and findtemplate is its function and hibbard.jpg is my image and window.jpg is my template )

```
function findtemplate(im,temp,th,showtemp)
out=normxcorr2(temp,im);
[m,n] = size(temp);
out = out(m+1:end,n+1:end);
bw = out>th;
if nargin >3
 im(1:m , 1:n)=temp;
end
clf
imshow(im,[])
hold on
for k = 1 : length( r )
 thisBB = r(k).BoundingBox;
 rectangle('Position', thisBB,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 );
end


im=rgb2gray(imread('hibbard.jpg'));
imshow(im)
temp=rgb2gray(imread('window.jpg'));
imshow(temp)
findtemplate(im,temp,.3);
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/koq8X.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6YKU.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioQyp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't understand what are you asking for. You can't draw the bounding box correctly or you can't find them?